# Build a Binary Space Partitioning tree for polygons

Tags: graphics, tree

[image: This is the example]
For picking the root, is there any rule to follow?
Let say if I pick E as the root, do I need to split E as G is crossing E?
I can understand the example on wiki [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning), but this one is more complicated (More polygons cross another)

If I don't need to split it, then what is the next polygon that I should pick as subset

[image: Tree that I draw]

Thanks in advance, this would help my study during Christmas

Comment: "For picking the root, is there any rule to follow?": you are asked to compare rule i, rule ii and your own.

Comment: Oh i see, but what will happen if a polygon cut through the root polygon? Do i need to split the root?

Comment: "Do i need to split the root?": no the root is already consumed.

Comment: Sorry for keep asking silly question. I tried to draw the tree and I think it has different ways to draw the tree, even if I follow the rule. For example, for pick a subset using least-crossed criterion, I can choose from A, C and D as they split only one polygon. Is that correct? Or I should pick the one that the closest from the Root (E)? Thanks